# Internal error running expressjs 4 on iis and windows azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have the basic express 4 app running locally using the node provided web server.

I attempted to view/edit in Webmatrix and use IIS so I could then upload to Azure as a node app. Azure's template uses older versions of node and express.

When run from Webmatrix using IIS - and when published to Azure, I receive the following:

```
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
```

I believe the issue is somehow related to the web.config file but all articles and fixes I've found are dated and have not resolved the issue.

My web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

<handlers>
  <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
  <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>

    <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
    </rule>

    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options -->
<!--
  <iisnode      
      node_env="%node_env%"
      nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
      maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
      maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="3"
      namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="2000"      
      maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
      maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
      asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
      initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
      maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
      watchedFiles="*.js"
      uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"      
      gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
      loggingEnabled="true"
      logDirectoryNameSuffix="logs"
      debuggingEnabled="true"
      debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
      debuggerPathSegment="debug"
      maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
      appendToExistingLog="false"
      logFileFlushInterval="5000"
      devErrorsEnabled="true"
      flushResponse="false"      
      enableXFF="false"
      promoteServerVars=""
    />
  -->


</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've contacted the Azure team and they've started a discussion but I have more faith in what stackoverflow users can provide.

Comment: assume you are using Azure App Service (aka azure websites). can you share your site name directly or in-directly https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: I created a blank express app - so can share the app. 
http://pulseexpnew.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matthew,

here is my guess, i think you didn`t config your app to listen to the right port when deploy to azure app service. you will need to do something similar to below code to get port number from enviroment valirable "process.env.port"

```
var app = require('express')();
var port = process.env.port || 8080; // 8080 for local or whatever number u want
var listener = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port); 
});
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks. I'll publish this on the post the Azure team published on MSDN. I'm also looking at the VStudio template and will test that as well.

Thanks.. greatly appreciated!